# Trigger a call to IRibbonExtensibility.GetCustomUI() to force a ribbon UI refresh

Tags: c#, ms-office, ribbon

I am developing an Office add-in. Due to some limitations of ribbon controls (e.g. `menuSeparator` has no visibility control or `splitButton` cannot host a `dynamicMenu` only a `menu`), I need to be able to cause the Office app to reload the ribbon by repeating a call to my add-in's `IRibbonExtensibility.GetCustomUI`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know ribbon add-ins, this would require to stop and then restart your add-in. There must be a way to do so given that one can access the list of add-ins in outlook. you could run another instance of your add-in which would first close the previous one, then return the updated ribbon XML. But this means that it would not be applicable while the user is clicking on the ribbon's components, and you would have to save all your data somewhere and then read it to restore the add-in status. In addition, the user may see the ribbon disapearing and appearing again, which may not be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Would the Ribbon.Invalidate() method work for your use case?  I frequently use it to refresh the ribbon when I've dynamically added/removed items.

For example, in the Ribbon c# file (Ribbon1.cs by default):

```
this.ribbon.Invalidate();
```

When the ribbon needs to be refreshed.  This assumes you've set this.ribbon in the Ribbon_Load method.

Comment: Yeah, but this won't use the new XML, will it?

Comment: That's a fair point - I looked back through my code and realized that I'm doing all my customization through the callbacks, which you specifically called out as not being available for those objects.  Could you 'unload' the original ribbon and create a new ribbon object with the updated XML?  Just conjecture, don't know if it's possible to have multiple ribbons.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to have (or affect) multiple ribbon tabs but I am not aware of any way to "unload" the ribbon and effectively make an Office app re-request your XML from scratch.